# tf.tile for blocks of tensor

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, repeat

I have the following tensor **a** and I would like to use tf.tile on it in two different ways to get different results.

```
a.eval() = array([[ 1],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       [10],
       [20],
       [30]], dtype=int32)
```

I know I can do:

```
a_rep = tf.tile(a, [1,2])

a_rep = tf.reshape(rep, (12, 1))
```

in order to get:

```
a_rep.eval() = array([[ 1],
       [ 1],
       [ 2],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       [ 3],
       [10],
       [10],
       [20],
       [20],
       [30],
       [30]], dtype=int32)
```

How should I use tf.tile to get the following result? I basically want **blocks of the tensor that have a specific size to repeat** instead of just one value.

```
a_rep.eval() = array([[ 1],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       [ 1],
       [ 2],
       [3],
       [10],
       [20],
       [30],
       [10],
       [20],
       [30]], dtype=int32)
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar trick, you tile the second dimension, but stack the "groups" across a new third dimension:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.constant([[ 1], [ 2], [ 3], [10], [20], [30]], dtype=tf.int32)
    group_size = 3
    repeats = 2
    result = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.reshape(a, (-1, 1, group_size)), (1, repeats, 1)),
                        (-1, 1))
    print(sess.run(result))
```

Output:

```
[[ 1]
 [ 2]
 [ 3]
 [ 1]
 [ 2]
 [ 3]
 [10]
 [20]
 [30]
 [10]
 [20]
 [30]]
```

This assumes that the number of elements in the array is divisible by the size group. If you want to support having a last "partial group" maybe you could do the above with the complete groups, tile the last bit independently and concatenate.